# How to access Kubernetes cluster network locally?

Tags: kubernetes, networking

I have a Kubernetes cluster on Azure that has access to an internal network. There are several websites in this network in `*.foo.com` domain. I would like to be able to access these websites from my local computer, both via browser and via CLI, but at the same time be able to access the public internet (the cluster cannot use public internet). How can I do that?

I know only about port forwarding, but it requires setting up separate tunnels for each address and using localhost to access the websites. I'd like to setup a kind of VPN that would route my traffic through Kubernetes in case I try to access `*.foo.com` website.